# Using opacity to blur a Div's background colour instead of mentioning rgba colour of a Div

Tags: html, css

I have an Image on the page. I have put a Div on footer with a heading and a paragraph inside the Div. I have made the Div's background transparent like this way , `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);`.
But I need to implement this like this way , `background-color:black; opacity:0.6"`.
The problem is, if I am doing it using opacity then the heading and paragraph is also getting blur with the Div's colour. How can I solve it?
Below is my full code.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }
    .feature-text-overlay {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        bottom: 0;
        padding: .6em 0 .8em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .feature-title {
        font-size: .875em;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color:white;
    }
    .feature-description {
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin: 0 2em;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
```

**Html**

```
<div class="div1">
    <img src="~/Content/Image/rendering-graphics-in-resolution-222734.jpg" />
    <div class="feature-text-overlay" style="height:52.599999277954px; min-height:1px;">
        <h4 class="feature-title">Enterprise Mobility Suite</h4>
        <p class="feature-description">Manages Users, Devices and Data</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.feature-text-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    padding: .6em 0 .8em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;    /* add this to specify position */
}

/* create pseudo css element */
.feature-text-overlay:before {
    content:"";
    background-color: #000;
    opacity:0.3;
    bottom: 0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/cnrnc5j0/1/)**

edit as per comment **[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/cnrnc5j0/2/)**

Comment: you must have forgot to give `position : relative` to `.feature-text-overlay`. Try the attached demo.

Comment: Yes i have edited mine as per your code but the div at the footer is coming below the image, not on the image. And heading and paragraph also isn't showing.

Comment: Again the heading and paragraph also is getting blur with the div's opacity. I want that the opacity will work only on the div, not in the heading and the paragraph. Please help :(